# When using 2 DbContexts, why is EF trying to add a relationship that should only be in one to both?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 `DbContext` classes in my application. The first is the usual `ApplicationDbContext`, which inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` it also contains some other tables linked to the user classes, such as content they have uploaded etc.

My second DbContext class is relating to another area of the application, which is to organise Clubs and Activities. This is called `ClubDbContext` and inherits from the standard `DbContext`.

The exact code works and migrates successfully when there is only one context, however, once I split the club/activity/organisation entities out into it's own context `ClubDbContext`, when i run the code, or attempt to add a new migration for the `ClubDbContext`, I get the following error message:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.Content' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.

The relationship it is talking about is defined in ApplicationDbContext as follows:

```
builder.Entity<Content>()
    .HasOne(c => c.Author)
    .WithMany(up => up.Content)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.AuthorId)
    .IsRequired(true);
```

The relationship it is talking about is specified in the `ApplicationDbContext` and there is no mention of the `ApplicationUser` or the `Content` classes in the `ClubDbContext` or any of the member classes...

The application works perfectly before the splitting of the single context into the two `ApplicationDbContext` and `ClubDbContext` - so the issue must be in the new context somewhere! I am at a loss... does anyone know why it is asking me to specify the relationship, when i have already, in the `ApplicationDbContext`??

I have added my two context classes to the following Gist:

https://gist.github.com/JorjeRedemption/bce50617ee40c5598d3f67dad73da25f

Comment: Does your `ClubMember` class inherit from anything in the ApplicationDbContext? ApplicationUser maybe? If so, that could probably cause a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, none of the classes in the `ClubDbContext` inherit from any class. Some of the models do implement interfaces that are used in the other context however, but i wouldn't have thought that would cause any issue? Could it!? Surely not...

Comment: Do any of the entities belonging to `ClubDbContext` have a reference to any entities belonging to `ApplicationDbContext`, or vice versa?  Not inheritance, but a *reference*?

Comment: Nope, before I removed the club entities from the single context, `Organisation` referenced `ApplicationUser` and vice versa. But this was definitely removed when i moved the entities into the new context. All that remains is the UserId field, which simply stores the creator's id, no actual relationship is created for this. Nothing as far as i can see connects the two contexts.